# how to update the values in android contacts

Tags: android

I am using  update method  to update my contact but when i go to my contact list to see the udpated number it shows me the previous number store , whats wrong with code can any sort it , how to udpate the contacts

ContentValues newPhone = new ContentValues();

```
        updateUri=Uri.withAppendedPath(uri, People.Phones.CONTENT_DIRECTORY);

        newPhone.put(People.Phones.TYPE, People.TYPE_MOBILE);
        newPhone.put(People.NUMBER, phone);
        //newPhone.clear();
        Log.v("--- PHONE NUMBER ","---VALUE ---- "+phone);
        //getContentResolver().update(updateUri, newPhone, null,null);
        getContentResolver().insert(updateUri, newPhone);

        Toast.makeText(NativeContentProvider.this, "Updated the phone number to: " + phone, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.i(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Updated the phone number");
```

Answer (score 0):

add permission to add/edit contact in menifest .
if already done , tell more about error you are facing . error log result will be very helpful  to understand

Comment: i am not getting any error but when i add the record is display that recorded added but with i click on the view button (which ) i have created for viewing the recorded its displays me only the name and the number is null ,same for update button when i click the update button its shows recorded updated but when i click on view it only display name with null value  i have added the permission